# An inequality of intersection multiplicities and products of algebraic multiplicities on singular varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a proper variety over a field $k$; $Z$ a sub-scheme of $X$ with dimension $d$; $D_1, \dots, D_d$ effective Cartier divisors of $X$. Suppose that $Z, D_1, \dots, D_d$ meet properly at a closed point $P \in X$.

If $X$ is non-singular, then by Fulton's *Intersection Theory* Corollary 12.4 we have
$$
i(P; Z, D_1, \dots, D_d; X) \ge \mu_P(Z) \cdot \mu_P(D_1) \cdot \dots \cdot \mu_P(D_d), 
$$
where $\mu_P(Z), \mu_P(D_1), \dots, \mu_P(D_d)$ are defined as in [GTM52] Chapter V, Exercise 3.4. In particular, we have
$$
(\mathcal O_X(D_1) \cdots \mathcal O_X(D_d) \cdot Z) \ge \mu_P(Z) \cdot \mu_P(D_1) \cdot \dots \cdot \mu_P(D_d), \tag{$\ast$}
$$
where $(\mathcal O_X(D_1) \cdots \mathcal O_X(D_d) \cdot Z)$ is defined as in [0BEL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BEL).

I wonder whether ($\ast$) remains true if $X$ is no longer non-singular.

Comment: I think if you take $X = V(xy - z^2) \subset \mathbb{P}^3_{xyzw}$, $D = X \cap V(z)$ a Cartier divisor (pair of lines on $X$), and $Z$ a general line through $[0:0:0:1] = P \in X$, then LHS = 1, and RHS = 2?